# Can I Insert C# in HTML String in Java script function?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, string, insert

[image]

Will `<%=this.Title%>` in the Javascript code be parsed by C#?

Comment: `this.Page.Title` is what you want so what's the problem..?

Comment: Just remember that Code Executes on the Server Before it gets spit out to the Client's Browser.

Comment: Please provide small sample as text and specify what file contains this code. In current state it is not possible to properly answer it (i.e. if it is just JS file why it would run any C#?) Additionally you probably already tried it and instead of "will it be parsed" you can actually ask why it does/does not work (and include results you see).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is if this is parsed rendered by the ASP.NET framework before returning to the browser. As in if you put these Javascript function inside an ASPX or ASCX file, ASP.NET will look for server delimiters and try to replace things inside first, regardless whether it's inside a Javascript string or not.

Comment: Note that whether output is valid JavaScript or not is completely open question, but most people don't use quotes in title :) so should be "fine".

Answer (score 0):

If this.Title is what you want `&& GetType(this) == Page`, you may want to replace

```
<%= this.Title %>
```

to

```
document.title
```